# Calculate transform-origin to scale image to middle of viewport

Tags: javascript, html, css, transform

I'm trying to calculate in javascript `transform-origin` property for absolutely positioned elements so that they fill whole viewport on hover.

I tried to calculate this property by dividing x by window width and y by window height where x is distance to the center of element from left viewport edge and y is distance between top of vieport  and the center of element. Unfortunately element isn't centered perfectly in that way and doesn't fill whole screen as I want to, although it has the right size to fill screen :/

How to calculate pivot position for `transform-origin` correctly to achive what I want ?

Here you have a demo:

```js
let blocks = document.querySelectorAll("a.block");
console.log(blocks);

Array.prototype.slice.call(blocks).forEach((block) => {
 console.log(block);
  let blockRect = block.getBoundingClientRect();
 
  let originX = (blockRect.left + blockRect.width /2) / window.innerWidth * 100,
   originY = (blockRect.top + blockRect.height /2) / window.innerHeight * 100;
 block.style.transformOrigin = `${originX}% ${originY}%`;
});
```

```css
.block{
  position: absolute;
  left: 5%;
  top: 10%;
  width: 10%;
  height: 10%;
  background: red;
  -webkit-transition: transform 1s;
  transition: transform 1s;
}
  
.block.second{
  left: 87%;
  top: 26%;
}
.block:hover{
  -webkit-transform: scale3d(10,10,1);
  transform: scale3d(10,10,1);
}
```

```html
 <a href="#" class="block"></a>
 <a href="#" class="block second"></a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I refreshed my knowledge of geometric transformations and I found the right mathematical formula.

```
transform-origin-x = scale * x / (scale-1)
transform-origin-y = scale * y / (scale-1)
```

where x and y is distance from the [left for x, top for y] edge, converted to the same unit as the width of the element.

To convert distance in pixels to percents you can:

```
Percentage x distance = left[px] / window.innerWidth[px] * 100
Percentage y distance = top[px] / window.innerHeight[px] * 100
```

```js
let blocks = document.querySelectorAll("a.block");

Array.prototype.slice.call(blocks).forEach((block) => {

  let blockRect = block.getBoundingClientRect();
 
 let originX = (10 * (blockRect.left/window.innerWidth * 100)) / 9,
   originY =  (10 * (blockRect.top/window.innerHeight * 100)) / 9;
  

 block.style.transformOrigin = `${originX}% ${originY}%`;
});
```

```css
.block{
  position: absolute;
  left: 5%;
  bottom: 10%;
  width: 10%;
  height: 10%;
  background: red;
  -webkit-transition: transform 1s;
  transition: transform 1s;

}

.block.second{
  left: 87%;
  bottom: auto;
  top: 17%;
}

.block:hover{
  -webkit-transform: scale3d(10,10,1);
  transform: scale3d(10,10,1);
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="block"></a>
 <a href="#" class="block second"></a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Is there any special reason why you want to do this with JavaScript? If you just want the animation, you can do it with pure css by simply setting the position and dimensions of your element to cover the whole page and use transition to animate it nicely:

```css
.block{
  position: absolute;
  left: 5%;
  right: 85%;
  top: 10%;
  bottom: 80%;
  width: 10%;
  height: 10%;
  background: red;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.block.second{
  left: 87%;
  top: 26%;
}
.block:hover{
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I have to use 3d transforms cause I need really smooth transition in that case. All elements are arranged randomly with js, so I can't use pure css since I don't know element positions on the run. In addition your solution doesn't work for elements attached to bottom edge: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4LxuyaoL/2/)

Comment: There was actually a bug. You have to set top,  left, right and bottom values in your initial .block definition. I have changed my answer to the correct version. There is a catch on that: when placing these boxes you have to calculate the correct percentage so that top + height + bottom = 100% but this should bei easy. It also should run smoothly since we are using built-in browser functions. But you have to check in this is smooth enough.

Comment: Thanks for help. I found the correct mathematical formula to do it in my way. I will test both solutions in terms of performance and will pick the best answer ;)